# IOS Web thread stopped when using webSocket in UiWebView

Tags: ios, xcode, webview

My Appliction stucked  when I connect my webview using WebSockets the error is

```
thread #7: tid = 0x0f3a, 0x2dd28894 CoreFoundation`CFRelease + 1132, name = 'WebThread, stop reason = EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=EXC_ARM_BREAKPOINT, subcode=0xdefe)
    frame #0: 0x2dd28894 CoreFoundation`CFRelease + 1132
    frame #1: 0x2ddc1d02 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopTimerDeallocate + 26
    frame #2: 0x2dd285f6 CoreFoundation`CFRelease + 462
    frame #3: 0x2dda0e70 CoreFoundation`__CFArrayReleaseValues + 192
    frame #4: 0x2dd285f6 CoreFoundation`CFRelease + 462
    frame #5: 0x2ddc10b0 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 1240
    frame #6: 0x2dd2bc26 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 522
    frame #7: 0x2dd2ba0a CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunInMode + 106
    frame #8: 0x35cb226a WebCore`RunWebThread(void*) + 418
    frame #9: 0x3885fc1c libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_body + 140
    frame #10: 0x3885fb8e libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_start + 102

    frame #11: 0x3885dc90 libsystem_pthread.dylib`thread_start + 8
```

Comment: I got problme  happen when I use to call javascript method by  [self.webview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:methodName] any answer

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I have the exact same problem - webview, calling `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString` and want to open a websocket. About 5% of the time, the WebThread will crash with the exact same stack trace you posted. Any solutions?

Answer (score 1):

Same crash here:

```
Thread 4 WebThread, Queue : (null)
#0  0x020020af in CFRelease ()
#1  0x05fc33eb in WebCore::stopSharedTimer() ()
#2  0x06173cd0 in WebCore::ThreadTimers::updateSharedTimer() ()
#3  0x0618c33e in WebCore::TimerBase::setNextFireTime(double) ()
#4  0x0618c284 in WebCore::TimerBase::start(double, double) ()
#5  0x05387ee7 in WebCore::DeferrableOneShotTimer<WebCore::CachedResource>::fired() ()
#6  0x06173da0 in WebCore::ThreadTimers::sharedTimerFiredInternal() ()
#7  0x06173c36 in WebCore::ThreadTimers::sharedTimerFired() ()
#8  0x05fc338b in WebCore::timerFired(__CFRunLoopTimer*, void*) ()
#9  0x0203eac6 in __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ ()
#10 0x0203e4ad in __CFRunLoopDoTimer ()
#11 0x02026538 in __CFRunLoopRun ()
#12 0x020259d3 in CFRunLoopRunSpecific ()
#13 0x020257eb in CFRunLoopRunInMode ()
#14 0x061d5e40 in RunWebThread(void*) ()
#15 0x033905fb in _pthread_body ()
#16 0x03390485 in _pthread_start ()
```

Appears to be a CFRunLoopTimer release message being sent to a deallocated instance

Comment: have you found a solution or did you end up using something else besides websockets?

Comment: sorry I haven't found a solution yet. I submitted the bug to Apple and they requested a test project which I haven't got round to sending them yet.